# Capture string that only has n words

Tags: regex, notepad++

In my case, I need n=2.

Can this be done with a regular expression? Looking for how many words there are in a string of text and capturing only the strings with 2 words?

Example:

```
this is a test string
another one
and another one
```

Output:

```
another one
```

For what I need, looking for strings where there is only one space should work, it's capturing the ones with only 2 words (or one space) that i don't know how to do.

Comment: Language? Can there be trailing or leading spaces? You don't want to capture one word strings, correct?

Comment: Is a "word" just every group of characters delimited by a space? E.g. the words of `"This is - a test." ` are `["This", "is", "-", "a", "test."]`?

Comment: @SebastianProske no flavor, going to do this in notepad++. There are no trailing/leading spaces in my dataset afaik. I don't want to capture one word strings, nope. @ Alexander yes. Eg: 10k race -> "10k" "race"

Comment: You can cover all the bases with `^\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+){n-1})\s*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something fairly simple like this should do you;

```
^\w+(?:\s\w+){1}$
```

More generally you can use;

```
^\w+(?:\s\w+){N}$
```

Where `N = n - 1` and n, as specified, is the number of words to capture.

Comment: ohh I see, you looked for a word, then for space+word and capture when there is only 1 space+word after the first word, right? clever, thanks :D

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately it doesn't - the optional space breaks the pattern, the test case `foo ` is matched incorrectly.

Comment: @TomWyllie hmmm I get it. Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

The most literal way to go would be

```
^\S+ \S+$
```

Using anchors and matching two groups of non-whitespaces separated by a space.

Comment: Just tried your answer, it works better than the other solutions if you need to match things like "a-b testing" because \w won't match "a-b" i think. So depending on if you need a more strict solution or not this should be used. Shame it cannot be accepted two answers ;)